# Zend Framework 2:: why inlineScript()->captureStart() is not working in layout.phtml

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I include `JS` file of my theme using `$this->inlineScript()->appendFile()` in `layout.phtml`.
After that I try to add some inline `jquery` code using `$this->inlineScript()->captureStart()` method.
The `jquery` code is not showing  but if I include that in action view page then `jquery` code is showing fine.
Can anybody guess what I am missing.
Here is my code snippets.

```
 echo $this->inlineScript()->appendFile($this->basePath() . '/assets/plugins/respond.min.js', 'text/javascript', array('conditional' => 'lt IE 7',))
                ->appendFile($this->basePath() . '/assets/plugins/excanvas.min.js', 'text/javascript', array('conditional' => 'lt IE 7',))
                ->appendFile($this->basePath('/assets/plugins/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'));


        $this->inlineScript()->captureStart();
        echo <<<JS
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                App.init(); // initlayout and core plugins
                Index.init();
                Index.initJQVMAP(); // init index page's custom scripts
                Index.initCalendar(); // init index page's custom scripts
                Index.initCharts(); // init index page's custom scripts
                Index.initChat();
                Index.initMiniCharts();
                Index.initDashboardDaterange();
                Index.initIntro();
                Tasks.initDashboardWidget();
            });
JS;
        $this->inlineScript()->captureEnd();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you capture additional scripts *after* you have echo'd the inlineScript helper output, how would you expect your additional code to be output? You either need to move your inline script above the echo in your layout, or move the echo to the end:

```
$this->inlineScript()->appendFile($this->basePath() . '/assets/plugins/respond.min.js', 'text/javascript', array('conditional' => 'lt IE 7',))
                     ->appendFile($this->basePath() . '/assets/plugins/excanvas.min.js', 'text/javascript', array('conditional' => 'lt IE 7',))
                     ->appendFile($this->basePath('/assets/plugins/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'));


$this->inlineScript()->captureStart();
echo <<<JS
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            App.init(); // initlayout and core plugins
            Index.init();
            Index.initJQVMAP(); // init index page's custom scripts
            Index.initCalendar(); // init index page's custom scripts
            Index.initCharts(); // init index page's custom scripts
            Index.initChat();
            Index.initMiniCharts();
            Index.initDashboardDaterange();
            Index.initIntro();
            Tasks.initDashboardWidget();
        });
JS;
$this->inlineScript()->captureEnd();

echo $this->inlineScript();
```

It works when you do it in the action because the action is rendered before the layout.